# "Trying to get property of non-object" from validate

Tags: php, laravel, request

for some reason that I do not know, when I try to pass a validation without request and try to use one if

```
public function save(Request $request){
    $request = $request->validate([
        'name' => ['string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
    ]);
    if($request->name != null){
        return $request;
    }

    return $request;
}
```

Comment: You are completely replacing the `$request` value from a `Request` type to the result from `validate()`. that means you will not be able to access `$request->name` as it might be bool

Comment: thanks man, but how could I use the if in validade()

Comment: @AlessandroAmos I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. Could you try to clearly explain what you are trying to do please?

Comment: @AlessandroAmos Try to be more specific about your problem. like, what are you trying to do? in which class you are getting the error and before all that search your question. e open-minded to the answers you read here. don't expect everyone just answer your question with no quality. add quality to your question

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing the type of your `$request` with the result from `validate()`

The validation will handle the what you wish to, so no need to worry. If you say the variable `name` is required, it will enforce it to not be `null` or `empty`;

So, just replace the result to a specific variable instead of replacing `$request` by doing:

```
    $validationResult = $request->validate([
        'name'  => ['string', 'required', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['string', 'required', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
    ]);
```

Better option than this is to create a specific request type by running

```
php artisan make:request YourRequest`
```

Your new class will be ready at `app/Http/Requests` where you can specify not only your `rules()` as you have in your array, as the `messages()` you wish each to output.

Then all you need to do is to replace your `save(Request $request)`
for `save(YourRequest $request)` which will kick in the validation before it triggers the method, which means you are at ease within the controller method to do the logic instead of having to double check your variables

Examples for common `rules()` within your class, will be:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:users|max:255',
        'name'  => 'required|min:2|max:200',
    ];
}

public function messages()
{
    return [
        'email.required' => 'The email field is required',
        'email.email' => 'The email field needs to be an email type. Ex:. type@gmail.com',
....
    ];
}
```

Obviously adjust the rules and messages to your project and liking :)